# how I can get ScrollBar Property in ScrollViewer C#

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, scrollbar, scrollviewer

I have this code:

```
Style barStyle = new Style(typeof(ScrollBar)); 
barStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter 
{ 
    Property = ScrollBar.BackgroundProperty, 
    Value = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue) 
}); 
Style ViewStyle = new Style(typeof(ScrollViewer)); 
...
Control.Style = ViewStyle;
```

In  `...` I want to set my ScrollBarStyle `barStyle` to my `viewStyle` of ScrollViewer. How I can do this? I want to change Color of ScrollBar in my ScrollView.

Comment: You don't add an implicit style to another style. Try adding it to the control's `Resources` instead: `Control.Resources.Add(typeof(ScrollBar), barStyle);`

Comment: thanks, I do it but ScrollBar Color is not change

Comment: Probably because the `ScrollBar` needs to be active for the color to change. An easy way to cope with this is by only showing active bars and setting `scrollviewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;`

Comment: WPF application or uwp app?

Comment: uwp, my `ScrollBar` is Visible, but Color not change. [link](https://pp.vk.me/c836133/v836133676/2855d/WZ19CHsftSU.jpg) Where I should set color to change? Set `ScrollBar.BackgroundProperty` is not work